# Different Groovy behavior for java.util.Date depending on whether the app is in a jar format or not

Tags: groovy, executable-jar, java.util.date

Ran into a puzzling situation... My Groovy (4.0.18) app is working smoothly (thanks to all the help I received!) So with IntelliJ's help I packaged it up into a jar file including all dependencies and it works nicely - except when it tries to use java.util.Date -- at that point the behavior changes.  If the app is executed through the jar file (java -jar myprogram.jar) then this exception is encountered -

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.format() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]
```

The code that it is trying to execute looks like -

```
    static String timestamp() {
        return new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    }
```

However, when the same code is executed prior to packaging it into the jar file it works smoothly.  All of the other Groovy functionality of the app works smoothly in either format; it accesses a database using Groovy Sql, it produces CSV files using Apache Commons CSV, parses the command line using CliBuilder, etc.  Considerable Groovy functionality leveraging a good bit of Groovy enhancements all without issue - except for this one Date.format() situation.

My (limited) analysis so far is that Groovy is executing the code (based on the groovy.lang.MissingMethodException exception), and it is executing Java's java.util.Date class but is looking for a Java method named `format()` which takes a single String argument and Java does not have a format() method but the expectation is that Groovy provides an enhancement.  According to the Groovy documentation -

```
String  format(String format)

        Create a String representation of this date according to the given format pattern.

String  format(String format, TimeZone tz)

        Create a String representation of this date according to the given format pattern and timezone.
```

Now in Java I think the situation is that instead of java.util.Date, java.util.DateFormat should be used - but this is Groovy and my understanding is that Groovy would take care of all that deprecation and Java details.

## Simple Test Case Reproduction

I was able to reproduce the issue with an isolated Groovy script -

```
static String timestamp() {
    return new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
}

println "${timestamp()} - hello world"
```

The simple test case runs successfully in IntelliJ and from the command line outside of IntelliJ -

```
$ groovy datetimeformat.groovy
2024-02-29 14:02:23 - hello world
```

but when IntelliJ packages it up into a jar file then an execution of `java -jar datetimeformat.jar` results in -

```
$ java -jar datetimeformat.jar
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.format() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]
```

Looking at IntelliJ packaging, it looks like it packaged up all the Groovy components that the program uses (and maybe more, the datetimeformat.jar file has 14,485 files in it) but particularly including what looks like the Groovy Date enhancements -

[image: IntelliJ packaging panel]

Not sure how to debug this situation and would appreciate any help/guidance/recommendation.

Comment: My guess is intellij is making a mess of the jar file. Are you using a build tool gradle/maven)? Or are you just using intellij?

Comment: Shot in the dark: intellij creates the fatjar by just copying all the
different jars into one; by that last META-INF files in win and so it's
up to dice, which features still work. Even if there is another
explanation I highly recommend using a proper build tool (e.g. gradle)
instead of using such features from your IDE.

Comment: Is the project anywhere we can actually see and test, to see what you are seeing?

Comment: Sounds like I need to learn how to build a jar file outside of IntelliJ... had hoped to avoid that but it'll be good for me...  :)

@tim_yates, the project is just on my laptop but the entire thing is reproduced in that little script above.

Comment: Hmm, gradle (v4.4.1) seems to be having an issue...

$ gradle init

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: The latest gradle is 8.6... where did you find dusty old 4.4.1?

Comment: Use sdkman (https://sdkman.io/) to install gradle, then this tutorial should help https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_groovy_applications.html

Comment: Ah, yea, that helped a lot.  That old 4.4.1 was from an Ubuntu apt installation.  sdkman did the trick and those samples help to get things moving in the right direction - thanks!

Comment: simply include `groovy-datutil` library to your dependecies explicitly

Comment: Take a look https://github.com/timyates/groovy-script-as-executable-jar I even added a test 

Comment: Nice example from @tim_yates. If you were using more than one module with extension methods, you'd typically want to also configure the shadow plugin to merge the extension method META-INF files using `mergeGroovyExtensionModules()`.

Comment: Updated with `mergeGroovyExtensionModules()`.  Thanks @PaulKing 

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates and @PaulKing!  Super appreciate the help, this would have taken me quite a while to figure out.  :)